# appengine oauth2decorater contacts api serviceName

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth, google-api-python-client

I've explored documentation but coulnd't find the serviceName to build a service object for handling the contacts API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to use the Google Contacts API: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/ ? If so, check out the sample code for python http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/samples/contacts/contacts_example.py that shows how to get access through the Google APIs client library. Because this API is a gdata API, it will look a bit different than the code for other google APIs which normally follow the

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
...
service = build("plus or some other service name here", "v1", http=http)
```

pattern, which is what it sounds like you were looking for.

Hope this helps!